# Unir dos columnas en una sola

Tags: r, r-dplyr, tidyverse

Tengo un dataframe en r, con las columnas nombre y apellido_1. Quiero unirlos todos en una columna llamada nombre_completo. Lo consigo fácil con `df$nombre_completo <- paste(df6$nombre, df$apellido_1, sep = "")`.

```
df <- data.frame(nombre = c('JOSEFA MONTSERRAT LOPE'),
                 apellido_1 = c('Z CARON'))
```

En el ejemplo puede ver, por ejemplo, como JOSEFA MONTSERRAT LOPE (en la columna nombre) y Z CARON (en la columna apellido_1) por lo que el resultado final que obtengo es JOSEFA MONTSERRAT LOPEZCARON y no JOSEFA MONTSERRAT LOPEZ CARON que sería lo deseable. ¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Tu pregunta no tiene solución , o al menos no una solución que cubra todo el universo de casos. Tienes dos ejemplos `c('LOPE', 'Z CARON')` y `c('LOPEZ', 'CARON')` ¿Cómo determinamos que los dos casos corresponden a `LOPEZ CARON`?

Comment: Podríamos decir "si el apellido empieza con una letra sola, entonces esa letra es parte del nombre", pero si hay más letras? y si la letra sola es parte del nombre?

Comment: Sí, son varios los casos así y entiendo que es imposible una solución universal. El "fallo" solo se produce si el apellido está realmente completo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias opciones de como hacerlo, por ejemplo usando la libreria `dplyr`, puedes agregar una columna usando la función `mutate`, y concatenando las columnas con `paste0`.

```
df |> mutate(nombre_completo = paste0(nombre, apellido_1))

                  nombre apellido_1               nombre_completo
1 JOSEFA MONTSERRAT LOPE    Z CARON JOSEFA MONTSERRAT LOPEZ CARON
```

En cuanto al código que estás usando, hay un error de tipeo en el código, ya que haces referencia a `df6`

Comment: Gracias Isaac, podría servir, pero hay algunos pocos casos en los que el campo apellido no está truncado (es un listado largo, solo he puesto un ejemplo). Me explico: en este caso funciona pero si es JOSEFA MONTSERRAT LOPEZ y después CARON como apellido_1, con mutate el resultado es JOSEFA MONTSERRAT LOPEZCARON

Comment: Una idea que se me ocurre es primero identificar esos casos y tratar de estandarizarlos, para luego concatenarlos.